# Project uses IEFrame.dll as browser won't work on Windows 10, any solution?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, windows-10, ieframe.dll

I have 2 projects use IEFrame.dll to browse the site. However when I upgrade my Windows to Windows 10, two applications just show me the white blank area, seems the IEFrame.dll doesn't work.

I see some article said the IE will not be the default browser in Windows 10, so the application cannot get the IEFrame.dll work. Is there a solution for this?

All my applications work well on Win7 and Win8...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several different things to get the page to load, I finally removed the registry key for FEATURE_BROSWER_EMULATION for the application EXE – I restarted the app, and it rendered the pages perfectly...